# Stop form by submitting weird bug

Tags: jquery

I am Just testing this code to stop form by submitting...

Jquery Part...

```
    $("#request_quote").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

HTML part...

```
<form id="#request_quote" method="POST" action="request_quote/requestSubmit" >
  <div>
    <label for="b_name">What is your Business name</label>
    <input id="b_name" name="b_name" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: i want to stop my form submission

Comment: Your latest edit is incorrect:  It should be `$("#request_quote").submit...` and `<form id="request_quote"...`

Comment: @AlizainPrasla - don't edit the question to remove the problem after you've accepted an answer, because after your edit the accepted answer doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form id is incorrect:  It should be `id="request_quote"`

Comment: +1 Just tested, this is the correct answer - easy to miss that!

Answer (score 1):

The code that you've shown should work fine, assuming it is run after the form has been parsed and added to the DOM - otherwise it won't be able to find any elements with the specified id. So either put that code in a script block somewhere after the form (e.g., just before the closing `</body>` tag), or put it in a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#request_quote").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

**EDIT:** Oops, just noticed what Steve pointed out in his answer, i.e., that there is a `#` in the id within the html markup - that should be removed and *then* if there is still a problem my comments about placement of the JS code will apply.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Steve, I saw your answer and was editing mine to note that point at around the same time you posted your (now deleted) comment. +1 to you.